# Regex to match a valid integer or decimal number (may be positive or negative)

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs, textfield

I want my ExtJS textfield to allow only numbers and decimals (Both positve and negative) .I need a regex to allow an integer or decimal number which can be positive or negative . 
Should match -

1)  123
 2)  123.23
 3)  -123
 4)  -123.23

Should not match for
   1)  --123
   2)  -2323-
   3)   23.23.23
   4)   34..34

Comment: what did you done to achieve this so far?

Comment: How is it a duplicate when it asks for regex and not Javascript functions?

Comment: Why are you not using 'numberfield'?

Answer (score 2):

`^-?((0(\.[0-9]+)?)|([1-9]+[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?))$` ([link](https://regex101.com/r/to35oy/3))

Tested it and it works on

```
0
1
12
123
0.1
1.12
12.0123
-1
-12
-0.1
-1.12
-12.0123
-0
```

And dosnt work on:

```
--123
-2323-
23.23.23
34..34
```

Comment: @varlogtim it matches all listed :) Even 1.1231231

Comment: Yeah, I changed mine to not be just 2 digist but one or more. Yours matches on "2." "3." it allows trailing dots. And there are a lot of parenths... It is late. :)

Comment: @varlogtim Its done. Forgot to take that into account.

Comment: Thanks for help . I think  Ext.isNumeric(num) would do same job.

Answer (score 1):

```
^-?(0|([1-9][0-9]*))(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

it doesn't work with

- 0123 due to leading 0 is meaningless
- 123. due to without number after decimal
- .123 due to without number before decimal

https://regex101.com/r/d3q4TI/1 to try it out

Comment: It does not match 1, 1.12, -1, -1.12,

Comment: fixed, thanks to pointing out

Comment: Thanks for help @Simon

Answer (score -1):

try this

```js
const regex = /^([-])?\d+(\.\d+)?$/

const validInputs = [123, 123.23, -123, -123.23, '-123.23', '-01.123']
const invalidInputs = ['--123', '-2323-', '23.23.23', '34..34']

for (const item of validInputs) {
  console.log(`test ${item} => ${regex.test(item)}`)
}

console.log('=======================')

for (const item of invalidInputs) {
  console.log(`test ${item} => ${regex.test(item)}`)
}
```

Comment: Test it with `-01.123`

Comment: added '-01.123', and it works fine

Comment: Precisely. That's not a valid number. In Javascript it raises `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`